# How do you loop iPhone sounds?

Tags: iphone, audio

Im working on a new game and i'm done but i just need to add some looping music, i have the sound file i want to loop, called theme.m4a How would you loop the music to play forever

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Core Audio Reference this may help.
[AVAudioPlayerReference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

When you get that just use the property:

```
@property NSInteger numberOfLoops;
```

Any negetive integer will infinitely loop it, 0 will play it once, and 1 will play it twice, etc.